# How can I restart my game?

Tags: transistor

I'm trying to restart [Transistor](http://supergiantgames.com/index.php/transistor/) game and I don't see any option to do so. I always start a new game by going in, seeing how it looks/feels and then you know, go around a bit and when I'm good, I restart the game from the beginning.

The problem here is that there isn't an option to restart the game at all. When I launch the game, the only option I see is "press any button" and when I do, it takes me to the last save location.

I've never seen this - not sure if its me or bad design/function decision but yeah, anything I can do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While in game, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the menu and click **Settings** -> **Profiles**. Select your profile, and press the left button **RESET PROGRESS**.